# Google test with Eclipse on Windows

Tags: c++, eclipse, gcc, cygwin, googletest

I am trying to setup google test with Eclipse.
This is what I have done so far:

Initial Setup:

1. Installed CDT on Eclipse Helios.
2. Downloaded and installed Cygwin.
3. Downloaded and extracted gtest.
4. built gtest using cygwin make using the default makefile.

In eclipse:

1. Created an empty executable c++ project with Cygwin in ToolChain.
2. Added "[gtest_dir]\include" in C++ Build/Settings/Cygwin C++ Compiler
3. Added library path as "[gtest_dir]\make" under C++ Build/Settings/Cygwin C++ Linker
4. Builder was already GNU Make builder
5. Wrote some example C++ code and built project.

I am facing the following error when I build the project:

Building target: SampleCpp.exe
Invoking: Cygwin C++ Linker
g++ -L/cygdrive/d/gtest-1.7.0/make -o"SampleCpp.exe"  ./src/Counter.o ./src/Counter_tests.o   -lgtest
**/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.8.2/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lgtest
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status**
makefile:45: recipe for target 'SampleCpp.exe' failed

What am I missing?

**EDIT 1** : [gtest_dir]\make contains two .a files - 
**gtest.a** and **gtest_main.a**

Also I'm using Eclipse Helios

**EDIT 2** :

It worked after I renamed **gtest.a** to **gtest.lib**. Is this the expected naming format for a library on Windows?

Comment: Is the actual GTest library (i.e. the object file) contained within `[gtest_dir]\make`? What about the name of the file? Does Cygwin link against `liggtest.a` or `gtest.lib`?

Comment: I am a little new to this so I am not able to understand what you mean by "_Does Cygwin link against liggtest.a or gtest.lib_". But [gtest_dir]\make does contain object files. I will update the exact names in some hours.

Comment: Different compilers have their own idiosyncrasies when it comes to library naming. For example, GCC prefers to give library `foo` the name `libfoo.a`, whereas MSVC goes with `foo.lib`. Having specified the library path as you did in step 3, I thought you might had built the library with a name other than the one considered by the linker.

Comment: I have a gtest_main.a file inside the[gtest_dir]\make......should it be renamed to gtest.a?

Comment: I now have compiled gtest.a also serperately from the Makefile. Now [gtest_dir]\make contains two .a files : gtest.a and gtest_main.a

Comment: Good, now you should link against those two files. Again, it might be the case that the toolchain you're using has its own way of looking for libraries. Does a Google (or Bing, whatever) search throw anything? I suppose there must be some examples out there that deal with linking an executable against a library.

Answer (score 0):

In project properties for your configuration, under C/C++ Build > Settings > Tool Settings > Cygwin C++ Linker > Miscellaneous > Other Objects, add $GTEST_DIR/make/gtest_main.a.

This makes the linker see gtest_main.a as an archive of object files, rather than a library.